# Axios request works locally but not on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, heroku, axios

I am making an axios request to the linkedin api on a node js server. It has been working for months fine and then suddenly stopped working on heroku. It still works from my local server and I can't find any information on the error. Any help is very appreciated. Here is the request and error.

```
      axios
        .get(
          "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee",
          {
            headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + account.accessToken }
          }
        )
        .then(linkedinCompaniesResponse => {
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

Here is the error message.

```
                  2021-12-06T03:09:32.038318+00:00 app[web.1]: { Error: write EPROTO 140034060351296:error:140920E3:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_hello:parse tlsext:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:1157:
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038327+00:00 app[web.1]: 
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038328+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038328+00:00 app[web.1]:     at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:863:14)
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038329+00:00 app[web.1]:   errno: 'EPROTO',
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038329+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'EPROTO',
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038330+00:00 app[web.1]:   syscall: 'write',
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038330+00:00 app[web.1]:   config: 
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038330+00:00 app[web.1]:    { transitional: 
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038331+00:00 app[web.1]:       { silentJSONParsing: true,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038331+00:00 app[web.1]:         forcedJSONParsing: true,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038331+00:00 app[web.1]:         clarifyTimeoutError: false },
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038332+00:00 app[web.1]:      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038332+00:00 app[web.1]:      transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038332+00:00 app[web.1]:      transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038333+00:00 app[web.1]:      timeout: 0,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038333+00:00 app[web.1]:      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038333+00:00 app[web.1]:      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038333+00:00 app[web.1]:      maxContentLength: -1,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038334+00:00 app[web.1]:      maxBodyLength: -1,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038334+00:00 app[web.1]:      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038334+00:00 app[web.1]:      headers: 
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038335+00:00 app[web.1]:       { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038336+00:00 app[web.1]:         Authorization: 'Bearer AQVx-yF7mYn7oqYhNYX8vxF3C3h_U5riZ4MjxS-AaDW40hweHGwu5UWcDdi30v35NgWpC2IzVmayaIqy44xO_YRFbbS2pU6PnASXEXh-afaDx6ZldrRDWXhDvjZ8e1qmkgPrEzKYJcgT89N-9T97dpHM9SM-lSoE3hB4w6JyihOECNQH8V8-wm4mm_TtCyv2AkxtoWMvVrqQ0ulgb4A3ULtemfyRBtqYxzBezKjGL5NBfXs81uzVna4IYRb1sl3qD4NxxNlhWrVsuOntRYaqEADf2pO45zp8uT2N4TjC4d2vBbIHyeCHQ-lvih1oHCzLxaWP6fUFeAFFQJ8DObbuJQNNqzbbew',
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038336+00:00 app[web.1]:         withCredentials: true,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038336+00:00 app[web.1]:         'User-Agent': 'axios/0.24.0' },
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038337+00:00 app[web.1]:      withCredentials: true,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038337+00:00 app[web.1]:      method: 'get',
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038338+00:00 app[web.1]:      url: 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee',
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038338+00:00 app[web.1]:      data: undefined },
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038338+00:00 app[web.1]:   request: 
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038338+00:00 app[web.1]:    Writable {
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038339+00:00 app[web.1]:      _writableState: 
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038339+00:00 app[web.1]:       WritableState {
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038339+00:00 app[web.1]:         objectMode: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038339+00:00 app[web.1]:         highWaterMark: 16384,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038340+00:00 app[web.1]:         finalCalled: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038340+00:00 app[web.1]:         needDrain: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038340+00:00 app[web.1]:         ending: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038340+00:00 app[web.1]:         ended: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038340+00:00 app[web.1]:         finished: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038341+00:00 app[web.1]:         destroyed: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038341+00:00 app[web.1]:         decodeStrings: true,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038341+00:00 app[web.1]:         defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038341+00:00 app[web.1]:         length: 0,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038342+00:00 app[web.1]:         writing: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038342+00:00 app[web.1]:         corked: 0,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038342+00:00 app[web.1]:         sync: true,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038342+00:00 app[web.1]:         bufferProcessing: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038342+00:00 app[web.1]:         onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038343+00:00 app[web.1]:         writecb: null,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038343+00:00 app[web.1]:         writelen: 0,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038343+00:00 app[web.1]:         bufferedRequest: null,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038343+00:00 app[web.1]:         lastBufferedRequest: null,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038344+00:00 app[web.1]:         pendingcb: 0,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038344+00:00 app[web.1]:         prefinished: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038344+00:00 app[web.1]:         errorEmitted: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038344+00:00 app[web.1]:         bufferedRequestCount: 0,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038345+00:00 app[web.1]:         corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038345+00:00 app[web.1]:      writable: true,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038345+00:00 app[web.1]:      domain: null,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038345+00:00 app[web.1]:      _events: 
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038345+00:00 app[web.1]:       { response: [Function: handleResponse],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038346+00:00 app[web.1]:         error: [Function: handleRequestError] },
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038346+00:00 app[web.1]:      _eventsCount: 2,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038346+00:00 app[web.1]:      _maxListeners: undefined,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038346+00:00 app[web.1]:      _options: 
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038347+00:00 app[web.1]:       { maxRedirects: 21,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038347+00:00 app[web.1]:         maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038347+00:00 app[web.1]:         protocol: 'https:',
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038347+00:00 app[web.1]:         path: '/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee',
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038348+00:00 app[web.1]:         method: 'GET',
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038348+00:00 app[web.1]:         headers: [Object],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038348+00:00 app[web.1]:         agent: undefined,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038348+00:00 app[web.1]:         agents: [Object],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038348+00:00 app[web.1]:         auth: undefined,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038349+00:00 app[web.1]:         hostname: 'api.linkedin.com',
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038349+00:00 app[web.1]:         port: null,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038349+00:00 app[web.1]:         nativeProtocols: [Object],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038350+00:00 app[web.1]:         pathname: '/v2/organizationalEntityAcls',
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038350+00:00 app[web.1]:         search: '?q=roleAssignee' },
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038351+00:00 app[web.1]:      _ended: true,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038351+00:00 app[web.1]:      _ending: true,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038351+00:00 app[web.1]:      _redirectCount: 0,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038351+00:00 app[web.1]:      _redirects: [],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038352+00:00 app[web.1]:      _requestBodyLength: 0,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038352+00:00 app[web.1]:      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038352+00:00 app[web.1]:      _onNativeResponse: [Function],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038353+00:00 app[web.1]:      _currentRequest: 
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038353+00:00 app[web.1]:       ClientRequest {
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038353+00:00 app[web.1]:         domain: null,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038353+00:00 app[web.1]:         _events: [Object],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038354+00:00 app[web.1]:         _eventsCount: 7,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038354+00:00 app[web.1]:         _maxListeners: undefined,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038354+00:00 app[web.1]:         output: [],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038355+00:00 app[web.1]:         outputEncodings: [],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038355+00:00 app[web.1]:         outputCallbacks: [],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038355+00:00 app[web.1]:         outputSize: 0,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038356+00:00 app[web.1]:         writable: true,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038356+00:00 app[web.1]:         _last: true,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038356+00:00 app[web.1]:         upgrading: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038356+00:00 app[web.1]:         chunkedEncoding: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038357+00:00 app[web.1]:         shouldKeepAlive: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038357+00:00 app[web.1]:         useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038357+00:00 app[web.1]:         sendDate: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038357+00:00 app[web.1]:         _removedConnection: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038357+00:00 app[web.1]:         _removedContLen: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038358+00:00 app[web.1]:         _removedTE: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038358+00:00 app[web.1]:         _contentLength: 0,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038358+00:00 app[web.1]:         _hasBody: true,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038358+00:00 app[web.1]:         _trailer: '',
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038359+00:00 app[web.1]:         finished: true,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038359+00:00 app[web.1]:         _headerSent: true,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038359+00:00 app[web.1]:         socket: [TLSSocket],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038359+00:00 app[web.1]:         connection: [TLSSocket],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038366+00:00 app[web.1]:         _header: 'GET /v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nAuthorization: Bearer AQVx-yF7mYn7oqYhNYX8vxF3C3h_U5riZ4MjxS-AaDW40hweHGwu5UWcDdi30v35NgWpC2IzVmayaIqy44xO_YRFbbS2pU6PnASXEXh-afaDx6ZldrRDWXhDvjZ8e1qmkgPrEzKYJcgT89N-9T97dpHM9SM-lSoE3hB4w6JyihOECNQH8V8-wm4mm_TtCyv2AkxtoWMvVrqQ0ulgb4A3ULtemfyRBtqYxzBezKjGL5NBfXs81uzVna4IYRb1sl3qD4NxxNlhWrVsuOntRYaqEADf2pO45zp8uT2N4TjC4d2vBbIHyeCHQ-lvih1oHCzLxaWP6fUFeAFFQJ8DObbuJQNNqzbbew\r\nwithCredentials: true\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.24.0\r\nHost: api.linkedin.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038367+00:00 app[web.1]:         _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038367+00:00 app[web.1]:         agent: [Agent],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038367+00:00 app[web.1]:         socketPath: undefined,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038367+00:00 app[web.1]:         timeout: undefined,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038368+00:00 app[web.1]:         method: 'GET',
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038368+00:00 app[web.1]:         path: '/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee',
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038368+00:00 app[web.1]:         _ended: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038368+00:00 app[web.1]:         res: null,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038369+00:00 app[web.1]:         aborted: undefined,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038369+00:00 app[web.1]:         timeoutCb: null,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038369+00:00 app[web.1]:         upgradeOrConnect: false,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038369+00:00 app[web.1]:         parser: null,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038370+00:00 app[web.1]:         maxHeadersCount: null,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038370+00:00 app[web.1]:         _redirectable: [Circular],
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038370+00:00 app[web.1]:         [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038371+00:00 app[web.1]:      _currentUrl: 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee' },
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038371+00:00 app[web.1]:   response: undefined,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038371+00:00 app[web.1]:   isAxiosError: true,
      2021-12-06T03:09:32.038372+00:00 app[web.1]:   toJSON: [Function: toJSON] }
```

I am using an express server. Here is my setup for that.

```
  const server = require("http").createServer(app);

  const allowCrossDomain = (req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    next();
  };
  app.use(allowCrossDomain);


  app.use(morgan("dev")); // Prints all routes used to console
  app.use(cookieParser()); // Read cookies (needed for auth)

  app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" })); //Read data from html forms
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true }));


  app.use(
    session({
      key: "connect.sid",
      secret: keys.cookieKey,
      resave: true,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      store: sessionStore
    })
  );

  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "./client", "build")));

  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
  server.listen(PORT);
```

I believe

```
  process.env.PORT
```

is port 80 as it if the default port on heroku.

Does anyone have any ideas? So confused by this.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I have checked all of those haha trust me.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I am adding more detail in the post. Thank you for letting me know. I don't understand the error message at all and have never seen something like it so I actually didn't know how complex it is.

Comment: `EPROTO` is a generic protocol error. Can you get to your Heroku instance and look into the logs? Your answer will most likely reside there. What are the versions of Node on your localhost that works vs on Heroku that doesn't work?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I edited the post to include the full error log from heroku. I am running node "node": "9.4.0", locally and on heroku.

Comment: @RandyCasburn like this? {
                headers: {
                  Authorization: "Bearer " + account.accessToken,
                  withCredentials: true
                }
              }

Comment: that may not work - that form may be deprecated. Try this instead: `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true`

Comment: @RandyCasburn That didn't work unfortunately. I updated my post to the new error message but it is basically the same. I am updating my node version to the most recent stable version.

Comment: OK - I'm no longer helping. Hope the node version fixes things.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Updating node version worked. I feel stupid. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are not the only one bitten by that reality. So glad you got it sorted.